# I need to redirect to a page that matches the type with HTACCESS

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-referer, http-redirect, redirect

If you go to my site at:

http://thaflynation.tumblr.com/post/41322801418/another-dope-track-by-tnght-r-u-ready/

It will redirect you to:

http://thaflynation.com

However i need it to redirect to:

http://thaflynation.com/audio/41322801418/another-dope-track-by-tnght-r-u-ready/

So i need to get the http referral: http://thaflynation.tumblr.com/post/POSTID/POST_SLUG
and redirect that referral to: http://thaflynation.com/audio/POSTID/POST_SLUG

how can i do this with HTACCESS? please help!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace `post` with `audio`, you must capture the part after post and append that onto audio

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?post/(.*) /audio/$1
```

If you want to have an external redirect

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?post/(.*) http://thaflynation.com/audio/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: I figured it out using php instead. Thank you!